# how to do calculation on dynamic row in table and then insert it into the database table using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

in this first i inserted the rows dynamically in the table after that i do calculation.my question is that how to do same calculation on 2nd row when added by clicking the add button then it save in the database using ajax in laravel 5.3 i tried but i'm not able to post it into the database for the single item.

```
<script>
var i=2;
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
    var data="<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td><td>"+i+".</td>";
    data +="<td><input type='text' id='description"+i+"' name='description[]'/></td><td><input type='text' id='part_no"+i+"' name='part_no[]' style='width:50px;'/></td><td><input type='text' id='quantity"+i+"' name='quantity[]' style='width:50px;'/></td><td><input type='text' id='rate"+i+"' name='rate[]' style='width:80px;'/></td><td><input type='text' id='discount"+i+"' value='0' name='discount[]' style='width:50px;'/></td><td><input type='text' id='taxable"+i+"' value='0' name='taxable[]' style='width:80px;'/></td><td><select id='cgst_rate"+i+"' name='cgst_rate[]'><option value='0'>0</option><option value='0.25'>0.25</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='5'>5</option><option value='12'>12</option><option value='18'>18</option><option value='28'>28</option></select></td><td><input type='text' autocomplete='off' id='cgst_amount"+i+"' name='cgst_amount[]' value='' placeholder='' disabled='' class='grid_input text-right' style='width:80px;'></td><td><select id='sgst_rate"+i+"' name='sgst_rate[]' class='grid_input'><option value='0'>0</option><option value='0.25'>0.25</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='5'>5</option><option value='12'>12</option><option value='18'>18</option><option value='28'>28</option></select></td><td><input type='text' autocomplete='off' id='sgst_amount"+i+"' name='sgst_amount[]' value='' placeholder='' disabled='' class='grid_input text-right' style='width:80px;'></td><td><select id='igst_rate"+i+"' name='igst_rate[]' class='grid_input'><option value='0'>0</option><option value='0.25'>0.25</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='5'>5</option><option value='12'>12</option><option value='18'>18</option><option value='28'>28</option></select></td><td><input type='text' autocomplete='off' id='igst_amount"+i+"' name='igst_amount[]' value='' placeholder='' disabled='' class='grid_input text-right' style='width:80px;'></td><td><select id='cess_rate"+i+"' name='cess_rate[]'' class='grid_input'><option value='0'>0</option><option value='0.25'>0.25</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='5'>5</option><option value='12'>12</option><option value='18'>18</option><option value='28'>28</option></select></td><td><input type='text' autocomplete='off' id='cess_amount"+i+"' name='cess_amount[]' value='' placeholder='' disabled='' class='grid_input text-right' style='width:80px;'></td><td><input type='text' autocomplete='off' id='total"+i+"' name='total[]'' value='0' placeholder='' disabled='' class='' style='width:80px;'></td></tr>";
  $('table').append(data);
  i++;
});
</script>
<script>
$('.delete').on('click', function() {
  $('.case:checkbox:checked').parents('tr').remove();

});
</script>
<script>
function select_all() {
  $('input[class=case]:checkbox').each(function(){ 
    if($('input[class=check_all]:checkbox:checked').length == 0){ 
      $(this).prop("checked", false); 
    } else {
      $(this).prop("checked", true); 
    } 
  });
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#quantity, #rate, #discount,#taxable,#cgst_rate,#sgst_rate,#igst_rate,#cess_rate').on('input',function(e) {

      var formdata = $('form').serializeArray();
      var quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val());
      var rate = parseFloat($('#rate').val());
      var taxable = quantity * rate;
      $('#taxable').val((taxable).toFixed(2));
// var taxable = parseFloat($('#taxable').val());
// $('#taxable').val((total).toFixed(2));

//for gst
var cgst_rate=parseInt($('#cgst_rate option:selected').val());
var sgst_rate=parseInt($('#sgst_rate option:selected').val());
var igst_rate=parseInt($('#igst_rate option:selected').val());
var cess_rate=parseInt($('#cess_rate option:selected').val());
// for cgst;
var cgst = taxable * cgst_rate/100;
// console.log(cgst);
// var net_cgst = taxable + cgst;
$('#cgst_amount').val((cgst).toFixed(2));
//for sgst
var sgst = taxable * sgst_rate/100;
// var net_sgst = taxable + sgst;
$('#sgst_amount').val((sgst).toFixed(2));
//for igst
var igst = taxable * igst_rate/100;
// var net_igst = taxable + igst;
$('#igst_amount').val((igst).toFixed(2));
//for cess
var cess = taxable * cess_rate/100;
// var net_cess = taxable + cess;
$('#cess_amount').val((cess).toFixed(2));
// alert(netgst);
var discount = parseInt($('#discount').val());
var total =  quantity * rate;
var total_disc =  total - (total*discount)/100;

var total_with_gst = total_disc + cgst + sgst +igst + cess;
$('#total').val((total_with_gst).toFixed(2));
$('#submit').click(function(){
// alert();            
$.ajax({  
  url:"/post/save",  
  method:"POST",  
  data:$('#description[]').serialize(),  
  success:function(data)  
  {  
    alert(data);  
    $('#add_name')[0].reset();  
  }  
});  
});  


});


  });
</script>

enter code here
```